# Powershell: NTFS paths in file metadata with New-ItemProperty, Set-ItemProperty?

Tags: powershell, properties, wmi, metadata, ntfs

I'm interested in adding a property to my files under a certain scope that contains their current locations in my file system, in order to track file movement. I would think that this could be done with New-ItemProperty, with a command similar to the following:

Get-ChildItem -recurse | foreach { New-ItemProperty -Path $*.FullName -Name "OriginalLocation" -PropertyType string -Value $*.FullName }

However, when I try this, I'm spammed with the following error:

**New-ItemProperty : Cannot use interface. The IDynamicPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not implemented by this provider.**

After some searching, it appears that New-ItemProperty is all but useless except for working with the registry. Fine. Windows has myriad other file properties I should be able to hijack in order to get this done. "Label" and "Tags" come to mind. So let's try setting those via Set-ItemProperty instead.

**Set-ItemProperty : Property System.String Label=D:\test\file.txt does not exist.**

It appears I need to create these properties after all. Is this a shortcoming of New-ItemProperty? Maybe setting properties such as this on arbitrary items is some WMI thing I don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution using the redirections ('<' & '>') that allow to manipulate alternate data stream in `CMD.EXE`. It works in Powershell without any extentions

```
# AlternateDataStream.ps1

$scriptBlockSetStream = {cmd /C `"echo $($Args[0])`>$($Args[1]):$($Args[2])`"}
$scriptBlockGetStream = {cmd /C `"more `<$($Args[0]):$($Args[1])`"}

$streamName = "NativeFilePath"
$File = "C:\Temp\ADSTest\toto.txt"
$streamContent = Split-Path -Path $File -Parent

# Set the data stream
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlockSetStream  -ArgumentList $streamContent,$File,$streamName
# Get the Data Stream
$res = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlockGetStream  -ArgumentList $File,$streamName
$res
```

Comment: Marking this as answer thanks to ease of portability. Thanks!

Comment: Why so complicated with `Invoke-Command`? Wouldn't `& $scriptBlockSetStream $streamContent $File $streamName` suffice?

Comment: My conviction is that : in a script, readabilty is more important than concision. I will use `&` operator in command line `Invoke-Command` is complicate for you but it's more readable for me than `&` operator, and as we are in a script it just needs a few more caracters.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to use [alternate data streams](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/01/27/powershell-accessing-alternative-data-streams-of-files-on-an-ntfs-volume.aspx) to store your path. If you are running PowerShell 3.0, you [can manipulate them](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/powershell-v3-betabetter-ntfs-alternate-data-stream-handling/) quite easily. Based on the first article, you would have something resembling:

```
"echo test" | out-file c:\powershell\test.ps1                                                                                         

$fs = new NTFS.FileStreams('c:\powershell\test.ps1')                                                                                  
$fs.add('OriginalPath')                                                                                                                  

$stream = $fs.Item('OriginalPath').open()                                                                                                
$sw = [System.IO.streamwriter]$stream                                                                                                 
$sw.writeline('<path>')                                                                                                  
$sw.close()                                                                                                                           
$stream.close()
```

Comment: I'm not running powershell 3, sadly, and while the articles you link are quite interesting, I've marked the other answer here as the solution thanks to its portability (even if it's a slightly less elegant wrapping of cmd). Still upvoted you though. Thanks!